# IE 8 and older not loading CSS

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, internet-explorer, firefox

I have developed website in HTML 5. Its CSS is not loading in IE old browsers IE 6, 7 and 8.

Second problem with my site is that its fonts are not loading in Firefox HTTP protocol but loading over HTTPS.

My htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (book_it.php|book-it.php|gccs.css)$
RewriteRule .? https: //%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(book_it.php|book-it.php|gccs.css)$
RewriteRule .? http: //%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
BrowserMatch MSIE best-standards-support
Header set X-UA-Compatible IE=8 env=best-standards-support
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>`
```

You can also view CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Use an IE8 only stylesheet - this will allow you to change elements or tell the user their browser does not support html5